# Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile Context in CommonMain

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, multiplatform

## Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile Context in CommonMain

Hi, I am currently exploring KMM developement and I am stuck on the Context part.

I want to create an class, that will handle secure data storing. I've created an **expect class Manager** and two **actual class Manager** for both iOS and Android. For the Android part the framework and all the other available tools require **Context**.

I want to use this **Manager** to store and read values in the CommonMain. From this shared part of the project there is no **Context** provided though.

How do I achieve this?

This is the code:

```
expect class TokenStore(context: Any) {
    fun getToken(): String?
    fun saveToken(token: String)
}
```

```
import com.liftric.kvault.KVault



actual class TokenStore actual constructor(context: Any) {
    private val store = KVault("com.example.keystoreexample")
    actual fun getToken(): String? {
        val token = store.string("ACCOUNT_TOKEN")
        return if (token != null) {
            println("✅ The token was found.\nThe value is: $token")
            token
        } else {
            println("❌ There is no token in the Token Store.")
            null
        }
    }

    actual fun saveToken(token: String) {
        if (token == "") println("⚠️ No token was provided.\nWatch out for this one.")
        if (store.existsObject("ACCOUNT_TOKEN")) {
            val existingObject = store.string("ACCOUNT_TOKEN")
            print("ℹ️ Object is already in the Token Store.\nThe token value is: $existingObject")
            if (store.clear()) {
                println("✅ All values in Token Store were removed.")
            } else {
                println("❌ There was an issue removing objects from the Token Store.")
            }
        } else {
            println("ℹ️ Object under this key is not stored in a database yet.")
        }
        if (store.set("ACCOUNT_TOKEN", token)) {
            println("✅ The token was added to the Token Store.")
        } else {
            println("❌ There was an issue inserting token to the Token Store.")
        }
    }
}
```

```
import android.content.Context
import com.liftric.kvault.KVault

actual class TokenStore actual constructor(private val context: Any) {
    private val store = KVault(context as Context)
    actual fun getToken(): String? {
        val token = store.string("ACCOUNT_TOKEN")
        return if (token != null) {
            println("✅ The token was found.\nThe value is: $token")
            token
        } else {
            println("❌ There is no token in the Token Store.")
            null
        }
    }

    actual fun saveToken(token: String) {
        if (token == "") println("⚠️ No token was provided.\nWatch out for this one.")
        if (store.existsObject("ACCOUNT_TOKEN")) {
            val existingObject = store.string("ACCOUNT_TOKEN")
            print("ℹ️ Object is already in the Token Store.\nThe token value is: $existingObject")
            if (store.clear()) {
                println("✅ All values in Token Store were removed.")
            } else {
                println("❌ There was an issue removing objects from the Token Store.")
            }
        } else {
            println("ℹ️ Object under this key is not stored in a database yet.")
        }
        if (store.set("ACCOUNT_TOKEN", token)) {
            println("✅ The token was added to the Token Store.")
        } else {
            println("❌ There was an issue inserting token to the Token Store.")
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use it here for example:

```
package com.example.keystoresample

// CommonMain
import TokenStore

class Greeting {
    private val platform: Platform = getPlatform()
    private val token = TokenStore(context).getToken() // Where can I get it?

    fun greet(): String {
        return "Hello, ${platform.name}!\nThe token value is:\n$token"
    }
}
```

I think I have tried a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Update: I've made a small library just doing what I have mentioned below. You can find more details about it from [https://github.com/psuzn/mp-utils](https://github.com/psuzn/mp-utils?tab=readme-ov-file#context-provider)

Edit: You can't get the context in `commonMain`. You should perform all the things that need context on `androidMain` source set. The example here is meant for the doing on the `androidMain` source set.

It probably is too late for this answer but I want to leave it here if anybody else is facing the same issue.

You can use the `androidx.startup` library to get the instance of the application context. You can store this in a variable and use it wherever you want. The application context lives throughout the application lifecycle so there is no issue with leaking a context. It is similar to injecting application context on the view model with the hilt.

Note: There is a difference between the context provided by the activity and the application context.

1. Add the `androidx.startup` dependency on your `androidMain` source set.

```kotlin
   val androidMain by getting {
       dependencies {
           implementation("androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.1.1")
        }
   }
```

2. Create an initializer class for the context

```kotlin
    import android.content.Context
    import androidx.startup.Initializer
    
    lateinit var applicationContext: Context
    
    class ApplicationContextInitializer : Initializer<Context> {
      override fun create(context: Context): Context = context.also {
        applicationContext = it.applicationContext
      }
    
      override fun dependencies(): List<Class<out Initializer<*>>> = emptyList()
    }
```

3. Register the `InitializationProvider` with the correct metadata on your manifest

```xml
    <application>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="merge">

            <!-- Replace com.example with actual package name -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.example.ApplicationContextInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />
        </provider>
    </application>
```

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Is something requires `Context` is has to be be moved to platform-dependent implementation.
You probably just need [KVault](https://github.com/Liftric/KVault).

Comment: You should be able to do the platform-specific thing on their own platform-dependent source sets. That's the fundamental reason why we have different source sets for each platform and also the `except`/`actual` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to not use `expect/actual` for such a task at all. Imho, it only confuses and makes code more complex. My solution was as follows:

In `shared/commonMain`

```kotlin
// Declare an interface to implement in Android and iOS
interface TokenStore {
    fun getToken(): String?
    fun saveToken(token: String)
}

// Declare a module with all app-scope dependencies
interface AppDeps {
    // There is just tokenStore for now
    val tokenStore: TokenStore
}

// Create a function for creating instance of AppDeps for all platforms
fun AppDeps(
    createTokenStore: () -> TokenStore,
): AppDeps = object : AppDeps {
    override val tokenStore: TokenStore by lazy { createTokenStore() }
}
```

In `shared/AndroidMain`

```kotlin
// Use android context for implementing TokenStore 
class AndroidTokenStore(context: Context) : TokenStore {
    override fun getToken(): String? {
        TODO("android-specific implementation here")
    }

    override fun saveToken(token: String) {
        TODO("android-specific implementation here")
    }
}
```

In `appAndroid` (whatever android app is called in your build)

```kotlin
class MyApp : Application() {
    val appDeps: AppDeps by lazy {
        AppDeps(
            createTokenStore = { AndroidTokenStore(applicationContext) }
        )
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        // appDeps can be used here
    }
}
```

Implementation for iOS can either be done either in `shared/iOSMain` or directly in your iOS app. To create AppDeps there you need to call `AppDeps()` factory function and provide iOS `createTokenStore` lambda with iOS-specific implementation.

Hope it helps.